# Automatically fetch preview image from given URL in Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I need help again from the community.

I'm interested to know how to extract a preview image from a given URL in rails.

Basically, it would be a functionality like you have on reddit. When user submits a link (fills in the link field in the _form), a preview image/thumbnail is automatically pulled from a given url. (I would like to save the link of the image as a field in the model, I don't want to save the image itself).

Is there a gem for that or? What's the best way to do it?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a gem 
github.com/gottfrois/link_thumbnailer
that does exactly what I wanted.

I tested it, and it works as described, so I can recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some wrappers around [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/):

> PhantomJS is a headless WebKit scriptable with a JavaScript API. It has fast and native support for various web standards: DOM handling, CSS selector, JSON, Canvas, and SVG.

It's also known for its ability to make web page screenshots.

I found a couple of gems for you: [screencap](https://github.com/maxwell/screencap) and [webshot](https://github.com/vitalie/webshot).

Example with `screencap`:

```
require 'screencap'

f = Screencap::Fetcher.new('http://google.com')
screenshot = f.fetch
```

You're also encouraged to check the documentation, it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but is there something that doesn't create a screenshot of a webpage?

For example, if you browse reddit's frontpage, you can see there are images that aren't screenshots, but certain images found on the destination url.

I'm looking for a way to implement that.

Comment: Maybe this would suit my needs:
https://github.com/gottfrois/link_thumbnailer

If I test it out, I'll leave my impressions here.

Comment: I tried link_thumbnailer, and it works exactly as I wanted - like a charm.

Comment: You should post it as a separate answer and accept it.